# Timer in command-line application

Tags: haxe, nme, hxcpp

Trying to create a simple command-line application in Haxe which has a ticking Timer, but it does not seem to work out; the Timer never actually starts 'ticking'.

```
package;

import haxe.Timer;

class TimerCallback {
    private static inline var CHAR_SPACE : Int = 32;

    public static function main() : Void {
        var myME = new TimerTicker();
        while (Sys.getChar(false) != CHAR_SPACE) {
            //loop until [space] detected, do nothing here
        }
    }
}

class TimerTicker {
    private var myTimer : Timer = null;

    public function new() {
        myTimer = new Timer(20);
        myTimer.run = timer_OnTick;
    }

    private function timer_OnTick() : Void {
        Sys.println ("foobar");
    }
/* destructor?! */
}
```

And this is the build command:

```
>haxe.exe -lib nme -main TimerCallback -cpp .\bin
```

If I am not adding `-lib nme`, the code does not compile (*based on API doc it's OK as Timer is not supported for cpp, so only static functions are available*)
If I am adding this, however, the code is compiled -as nme supports cpp Timers-, and the exe is created (win), but `timer_OnTick()` is never called. So exe starts, nothing happens, one press `SPACE` and app. quits.
Additional info:
 - The imported `Timer.hx` file is this one: `haxe\lib\nme\5,1,8\haxe`. And if I am right, this should be OK & working.
 - Using haxe 3.1.3, nme 5.1.8, hxcpp 3.1.39 (and haxelib 3.1.0-rc.4 if matters)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've got help from the Haxe Community (mailing list). Here are the solutions if anyone happen to need them:
PSEUDO CODE (not tested)

```
class RunLoop {
   static var queue = new Deque<Void->Void>();
   static var keepAlives:Int; = 1;
```

static public function release()
       enque(function () keepAlives--);

static public function retain()
       enque(function () keepAlives++);

static public function enque(task:Void->Void)
       queue.add(task);

static function main() {
       enque(entryPoint);
       release();
   }
   static function entryPoint() {
       //code goes here
   }
   static function run()
       while (keepAlives:Int > 0)
           queue.pop()();
}

//Now you can go an implement a timer like so:

class Timer {
    var active:Bool = true;
    public function new(msecs:Int) {
        RunLoop.retain();
        Thread.create(function () while(active) {
            Sys.sleep(msecs / 1000);
            if (active)
                RunLoop.enque(this.run);
        });
    }
    public dynamic function run() {}
    public function stop() {
       active = false;
       RunLoop.release();
    }
}

//And a helper for blocking code:

class Task {
    var task:Void->T;
    var onDone:T->Void;
    public function new(task:Void->T, onDone:T->Void) {
         RunLoop.retain();
         Thread.create(function () {
             var result = task();
             RunLoop.enque(onDone.bind(result));
         });
    }
}

//So then the code you want would look roughly like this:

static function entryPoint() {
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.run = function () trace('foobar');
    function waitForSpace() {
        while (Sys.getChar(false) != CHAR_SPACE) {
           //loop until [space] detected, do nothing here
        }
        return true;
    }
    new Task(
       waitForSpace,
       function (_) timer.stop() //stop the timer so that the run loop can exit
    );
} (solution provided by back2dos)

```
/*
1. Neko : works
2. C++: works, However, incrementing count in the if statement instead ( if( count++ == 0 ) { ... ) fails to increment count!  Fixed on Git?
3. Flash : works
4. Java : fails using Haxe 3.1.3
*/
```

###  build.hxml  ###

-main Main
-swf main.swf
-swf-version 12

--next

-main Main
-neko main.n

--next

-main Main
-cpp cpp
-cmd cp cpp/Main ./main

--next

-main Main
-java java
-cmd cp java/Main.jar ./main-jar

###  Main.hx  ###

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        #if sys
        var count = 0;
        while( true ) {
            if( count == 0 ) {
                Timer.delay(function() trace("doThing1"), 3000);
                Timer.delay(function() trace("doThing2"), 1000);
                count++;
            }
        }
        #else
        Timer.delay(function() trace("doThing1"), 3000);
        Timer.delay(function() trace("doThing2"), 1000);
        #end
    }
}

###  Timer.hx  ###

#if neko
import neko.vm.Deque;
import neko.vm.Thread;
import neko.vm.Mutex;
import neko.vm.Lock;
 #elseif cpp
import cpp.vm.Deque;
import cpp.vm.Thread;
import cpp.vm.Mutex;
import cpp.vm.Lock;
 #elseif java
import java.vm.Deque;
import java.vm.Thread;
import java.vm.Mutex;
import java.vm.Lock;
 #end

class Timer {
    #if sys
    static var timerThread : TimerThread;
    #else
    static var timers : Array;
    #end

```
static function __init__() {
    #if sys
    timerThread = new TimerThread();
    #else
    timers = [];
    #end
}

public static function stop() {
    #if sys
    timerThread.quit();
    #else
    for( t in timers )
        t.stop();
    #end
}

public static function delay( func : Void -> Void, delayMillis : Int ) {
    #if sys
    timerThread.addTimer(delayMillis/1000, func);
    #else
    timers.push( haxe.Timer.delay(func, delayMillis) );
    #end
}
```

}
 #if sys
typedef TTimerData = {
    time : Float,
    func : Void -> Void
}

class TimerThread {
    var mutex : Mutex;
    var queueLock : Lock;
    var queue : Array;
    var running : Bool;
    public function new() {
        queue = [];
        queueLock = new Lock();
        mutex = new Mutex();
        running = true;
        Thread.create( mainLoop );
    }
    public function addTimer( delaySec : Float, cb : Void -> Void ) {
        mutex.acquire();
        var time = haxe.Timer.stamp() + delaySec;
        var index = 0;
        while( index < queue.length && time >= queue[index].time )
            index++;
        queue.insert(index, { time : time, func : cb });
        mutex.release();
        queueLock.release();
    }
    public function quit( ?cb : Void -> Void ) {
        var me = this;
        addTimer( 0, function() {
            me.running = false;
            if( cb != null ) 
                cb();
        } );
    }
    function mainLoop() {
        while( running ) {
            var wake : Null = null;
            var now = haxe.Timer.stamp();
            var ready = new Array();
            mutex.acquire();
            while( queue.length > 0 )
                if( queue[0].time <= now )
                    ready.push(queue.shift());
                else {
                    wake = queue[0].time;
                    break;
                }
            mutex.release();
            for( d in ready ) {
                d.func();
                if( !running )
                    break;
            }
            if( !running )
                break;
            if( wake == null )
                queueLock.wait();
            else {
                var delay = wake - haxe.Timer.stamp();
                if( delay > 0 )
                    queueLock.wait(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
 #end
 (Solution provided by Zjnue, modified code of Hugh)